# Editable TextBox-es in ListBox C#

Tags: c#

I want to create application (Windows Form Application) that creates mathematical tasks for children from random numbers based on user input (max number to count, and number of tasks). Right now I'm working with addition. So far I have created 4 lists. First is a list of random numbers(let's say 3,7,1,5).

```
public List<int> CreateRandomNumbers(int maxNumberByUser, int tasks)
    {
        var random = new Random();
        var randomNumbersList = new List<int>();
        int numberOfNumbers = tasks * 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfNumbers; i++)
        {
            randomNumbersList.Add(random.Next(maxNumberByUser + 1));
        }
        return randomNumbersList;
    }
```

Second list is list of even indexed numbers from first list(3,1).

```
public List<int> EvenIndexesRandomNumbersList(List<int> randomList)
    {
        List<int> evenIndexesRandomNumbersList = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < randomList.Count; i++)
        {
            if ((i % 2) == 0)
            {
                evenIndexesRandomNumbersList.Add(randomList[i]);
            }

        }
        return evenIndexesRandomNumbersList;
    }
```

3rd list is list of odd numbers from first list(7,5),

```
public List<int> OddIndexesRandomNumbersList(List<int> randomList)
    {
        List<int> oddIndexesRandomNumbersList = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < randomList.Count; i++)
        {
            if ((i % 2) != 0)
            {
                oddIndexesRandomNumbersList.Add(randomList[i]);
            }
        }
        return oddIndexesRandomNumbersList;
    }
```

and fourth list is a list of sums (3+7,1+5, so 10,6).

```
public List<int> AdditionResultsList(List<int> evenList, List<int> oddList)
    {
        List<int> resultsList = new List<int>();
        resultsList = evenList.Zip(oddList, (x, y) => x + y).ToList();
        return resultsList;
    }
```

Finally, I have created a ListBox in witch tasks will be displayed like this:

```
public void CreateAdditionTasks(int tasks, Panel panel, List<int> evenNumbers, List<int> oddNumbers)
    {
        ListBox listBox1 = new ListBox();
        List<int> evenIndexesList = evenNumbers;
        List<int> oddIndexesList = oddNumbers;
        TextBox resultContainer = new TextBox();
        resultContainer.Text = "";
        listBox1.Size = new Size(400, 300);
        listBox1.Location = new Point(400, 300);
        panel.Controls.Add(listBox1);
        listBox1.MultiColumn = false;
        listBox1.BeginUpdate();
        for (int i = 0; i < tasks; i++)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("Task number " +(i+1)+ ":    " + evenIndexesList[i] + "  +  " + oddNumbers[i] + "  =  "+ resultContainer.Text);
            
        }
        
        listBox1.EndUpdate();
    }
```

Now, my idea is to allow user to input solution for every task in the final resultContainer which is TextBox, and based on input, I want that task green for correct or red for incorrect.
Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Is there a reason you're dynamically generating all your controls? This is an advanced topic, and you would normally use the designer to place all your controls on the form and give them reasonable default property values. Then you only need to change the value(s) you need in your code.

Comment: So...is the user supposed to enter ALL the solutions in the TextBox, one answer per line?  Or do they select ONE task from the ListBox, then enter just that solution in the TextBox and press a Button to check?

Comment: User can enter solution in any line, but when they do that and let's say press Enter, the whole line will go green if the answer is correct, or red if not. Also, when user enter all the solutions to all lines, based on the inputs, he will get grade.

Comment: It'd be very difficult to do the coloring with a TextBox.  It could be done with a RichTextBox, but it will again be difficult and clunky as the enters and changes text.  A DataGridView would be the best solution.  You could use a third ListBox for the user answers, but the enter the value in a separate TextBox and then hit a Button to add the value to the third ListBox.  The whole interface needs a rethink in my opinion...

Comment: Ok, what I'm trying here is to create list of mathematic tasks based on user input like. First user select "Addition", then he gets "how many tasks do you want", and he write, let's say 5. Application then generates something like: Taks number 1: 5+6=TextBox

Comment: and so on, 5 tasks

Comment: Right...your problem description is fine.  Another approach would be to build a custom UserControl that simply contains a Label for the Math Problem, and a TextBox for the user to enter their answer.  You'd pass the problem and answer to the UserControl as you create them.  Then you'd simply add all of your UserControls to a FlowLayoutPanel and they'd magically arrange themselves.  Since each TextBox (inside the UserControl) would only be ONE line, it'd then make sense to change the BackColor to a different color.

Comment: Yes, i have tried with Labels first, but what if user input 200 tasks?

Comment: "but what if user input 200 tasks"...again, [DataGridView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/datagridview-control-overview-windows-forms)...

Comment: Thank you, I will try.

Comment: I think for a smaller, reasonable amount of tasks, the UserControl approach would be nicer since you would have great control over how the tasks look and are arranged.  The DataGridView would certainly be able to handle a large number of tasks, but it will be boring to the user.